Counter example in logics
Studying logics I saw the following problem:
If Δ ⊨ α and Γ ∪ {α ∧ β} ⊨ δ, then Γ ∪ Δ ⊨ δ.
So, using valuation, I concluded that it is false. But, I need to find a counter example to convince myself. I tried to do the following:
Let Δ = {p}
Let α = p
Let Γ = {q}
Let β = ¬q
Let δ = r
Now, let's check the conditions:
Δ ⊨ α is true because {p} ⊨ p
Γ ∪ {α ∧ β} ⊨ δ is true because:
{q} ∪ {p ∧ ¬q} ⊨ r
This is vacuously true because p ∧ ¬q is a contradiction with q, so any conclusion follows from a contradiction.
However, Γ ∪ Δ ⊨ δ is false because:
{q} ∪ {p} ⊭ r
There's no way to derive r from p and q alone.
Is this valid?

Looks fine! The last sentence "No way to derive $r$ from $p$ and $q$" might be considered a bit hand-wavy by some. It becomes a very solid counterexample if you explicitly interpret $p$ and $q$ as true and $r$ as false.

@Tzimmo but it does not contradicts the condition of the valuation of all formulas be one in Γ ∪ {α ∧ β}?

The notation $\Gamma \models \alpha$ means the following: For all possible way of assigning "true" and "false" to the variables, if all formulas in $\Gamma$ become true, so does $\alpha$. If an element of $\Gamma$ (or, in this case, $\Gamma \cup {\alpha \wedge \beta}$) is false, this statement is true. The condition inside the "if"-clause is false, so there is nothing more to check.

Also the notation $\Sigma\not\models\gamma$ means: there are assignments of variables for which all formula in $\Sigma$ are valued as true, but $\gamma$ is valued as false.

There is no need to introduce $p,q,$ or $r$ when $\alpha,\beta,$ and $\delta$ are already doing that job.
All you need are examples for $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ where:

$ \Delta\models\alpha$ and $\Gamma\cup\{\alpha\land\beta\}\models\delta$, but $\Gamma\cup\Delta\boldsymbol{\not\models}\delta$.

Well, you have effectively chosen $\Delta=\{\alpha\}$ and $\Gamma=\{\neg\beta\}$.  So let us see if we can show:

$ \{\alpha\}\models\alpha$ and $\{\neg\beta\}\cup\{\alpha\land\beta\}\models\delta$, but $\{\neg\beta\}\cup\{\alpha\}\boldsymbol{\not\models}\delta$.

The first is trivial: Clearly all interpretations valuing $\alpha$ as true must value $\alpha$ as true.
The second is vacuously true: Since no interpretation may value both $\neg\beta$ and $\alpha\land\beta$ as true.
The third could be demonstrated by any interpretation that values $\neg\beta$ and $\alpha$ as true but $\delta$ as false.


So, that all checks out okay.

